# getting these scores in confusion in confusion matrix. can somebody guide me what could be the reasons

Tags: machine-learning, classification

getting these scores in confusion in confusion matrix. can somebody guide me what could be the reasons. Actually all features are categorical in my data and I have done frequency encoding technique. Not sure what needs to be done ti improve my scores :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YHU9.png)

Comment: Perhaps one day there will be enough data points in the training set that the machine learning community will learn that the [tag:ml] tag refers to a family of programming languages.

Comment: please provide all information in your question. What kind of data, what model...

Comment: It a classification model having and I wanted to know if the above (image mentioned) confusion matrix is pointing towards some problem with my model. I have only categorical values in my features and output is binary. Even if  i remove or more column , scores still remains same.